# Create 3D Mesh from Image automatically

Tags: mesh, image

I want to write a script that creates a 3D Mesh based on an Image (as plane).
My workflow now is:

- import image as plane
- subdivide plane
- bake image as vertex color
- delete vertices based on their color
- Decimate Modifier
- Solidify Modifier
- Subdiv Modifier

This is the result I get:

[image]

All of this must be achieved with the script so tracing the shape by hand is not possible. Do you know any other approaches to this, that might be useful?

Comment: I don't know of any specific add-on that has exactly that workflow; but with one exception it would be pretty easy to write a script to do what you want.  The exception is "delete vertices based on their color".  That would depend on how you wanted to go about selecting the colors to delete and could vary from something simple like how close to black the pixel is to something complex enough to require an AI-based tool.  How do you decide the color now?

Comment: I'll write the script, it's just about the workflow.
Selecting the color should not be an issue since I can create black and white masks, which makes it very simple.

Comment: You can look at addons like [easy bake](https://github.com/leukbaars/EasyBake) to see how the baking is done.  Once baked, I would use [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html) for the mesh manipulations.  Adding the modifiers is pretty easy.  Good luck

Comment: There's an add-on that does this already: https://github.com/Banbury/io_image_as_mesh you might find some helpful information in their process

Comment: @MartyFouts Can you maybe help me with bmesh? How can I delete vertices that don't belong to a surface?
Right now I am doing the following:
- select mode to face select
- select all faces
- select mode to vertex
- invert selection
- delete

However this is extremly unstable and I guess thats the reason why bmesh should be used but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: @Timmethy do I understand that you're trying to delete vertices that are not part of any face?  If so, ask that as a separate question and I'll write up an answer there.  If not, think about how to describe what you want, not how you're doing it, and write that up as a separate question.  Several people here might be able to help you.

Comment: Did so, thank you :)

Comment: @Timmethy I hope my answer there helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following my initial workflow and with your help my script is now working. This is the result:
[image]

Here is also the script in case it is helpful for someone:

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
loops = len(ob.data.loops)
verts = len(ob.data.vertices)
visit = verts * [False]
sel_v = []

#SET THRESHOLD VALUES HERE

r = 0.2
g = 1
b = 1

#CREATE VERTEX COLOR LAYER

bpy.ops.mesh.vertex_color_add()    

#BAKE TEXTURE TO VERTEX COLOR

bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
bpy.context.scene.render.bake.target = 'VERTEX_COLORS'
bpy.ops.object.bake(type = 'DIFFUSE') 

#SELECT VERTICES BASED ON VERTEX COLOR

for l in range(loops):
    v = ob.data.loops[l].vertex_index
    c = ob.data.vertex_colors[0].data[l].color
    if not visit[v]:
        if c[0] < r and c[1] < g and c[2] < b:
            sel_v.append(v)
        visit[v] = True
        
#REMOVE VERTICES WITH BMESH

verts = []
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()

for i in sel_v:
    verts.append(bm.verts[i])
    
for i in verts:
    bm.verts.remove(i)


for vert in bm.verts:
    vert.select = False

#DELETE VERTICES THAT ARE NOT PART OF ANY FACE

for face in bm.faces:
    face.select_set(True)

for vert in bm.verts:
    vert.select_set(not vert.select) 
    
for vert in bm.verts:
    if vert.select:
        bm.verts.remove(vert)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

#CREATE MODIFIERS

size = max(ob.dimensions)

dec = ob.modifiers.new(name = "dec", type = 'DECIMATE')
dec.decimate_type = 'DISSOLVE'

sol = ob.modifiers.new(name = "sol", type = 'SOLIDIFY')
sol.thickness = size/3
sol.offset = 0

sub = ob.modifiers.new(name = "sub", type = 'SUBSURF')
sub.levels = 2
```